# How do I constantly poll a table in Postgresql using Listen and Notify mechanism?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, postgresql, python-asyncio

My aim is to tail a table called `logs` in a postgresdb, get each row inserted and extract data from it. It could be the case that 10 rows are inserted at once and I process each of them, and then poll again. It has to be a forever logic (`while True`).

I created a trigger using the following two statements:

```
create or replace function public.notify_logsevent()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $function$
begin
    perform pg_notify('new_logsevent', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
    return null;
end;
$function$
;

create trigger new_log_trigger 
after insert on logs 
for each row execute procedure notify_logsevent();
```

Now, I want to tail all the logs in my Python code. So, this is the code I wrote:

```
import json
import os
import random
import time
import asyncio

import psycopg2
from prometheus_client import (Enum, Gauge, Histogram, Info, Summary,
                               start_http_server)

def db_connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='superset', password='password', dbname='superset', port='5433'):
    postgres_connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=host, user=user, password=password, dbname=dbname, port=port)
    return postgres_connection


def set_isolation_level(db_connection):
    db_connection.set_isolation_level(
        psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)


def listen_logs(db_connection):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()

    def listen_callback():
        nonlocal db_connection
        db_connection.poll()
        queue.put_nowait(db_connection.pop(0))

    async def print_queue():
        while True:
            data = await queue.get()
            if data is None:
                return
            else:
                print("Notification received: ", data)

    def stop_queue():
        print("Stopping queue")
        queue.put_nowait(None)
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_reader(db_connection, listen_callback)


    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("LISTEN new_logsevent")
    print("hello")


def main():
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)
    # Connect with the database
    db_connection = db_connect()
    set_isolation_level(db_connection)
    # get all the columns
    listen_logs(db_connection)


main()
```

My issue is, the code gets executed but it gets terminated and no tailing or fetching is done. I want it to keep polling the database and as soon as the new row arrives, fetch it and print it here. I am looking for a functionality of `tail cursor` in MongoDB.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't use asyncio properly. For one, it never appears to run the event loop. Second, it uses low-level APIs like `add_reader` improperly (they should never be used by application code, they serve to implement libraries). You should use an async-aware library like [asyncpg](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg).

Comment: Can you submit an answer that would include the minimal code for listening to postgresql events?

Comment: Sorry, that's not how StackOverflow works. The answer would depend on precisely what you mean by "listening to events" and how the rest of your application works. Try using asyncpg, and if you have a concrete question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: There is also psycopg 3 which supports notifications via blocking API efficiently and also provides an asyncio API; https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/async.html#asynchronous-notifications